# What is the minimum score to get a scholarship?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

The test scores of an entrance examination are normally distributed with a mean $230$ and standard deviation $80$, the cutoff for admission was $310$ what % of examinees got admission, further, the upper $2$% received scholarships, what is the minimum score to get a scholarship?

Let our random variable be the score of a student got.
Now first i need to find $P(X>310)$
i.e \begin{align} P(Z>1)=
&1-P(Z\le1)\\
             &= 1-0.8413\\
             &= 0.1587 \\
\end{align}
Now I'm stuck here how do i find the minimum score to get the scholarship?

Comment: Use inverse normal

Comment: Just for mere curiousity. Is this an exercise or a real life situation?

Comment: @DavidQuinn Do i need to find $P(Z>\frac{x-230}{80})$=$ 0.02 $? Where $x$ is minimum score?

Comment: Yes now find $x$

Comment: My doubt is that since there are $15.87$ % student who cleared the exam now this $2$% is of $15.87$ or  of $100 $%

Comment: The wording of the question is not clear, but presumably it’s 2% of the total cohort